# How to avoid "Unable to get property 'X' of undefined or null reference" when creating $scope properties from JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to populate some charting data from some JSON data pulled down using `$http.get`. However, the issue I have is the `$scope` property I am binding to doesn't exist until the JSON is returned, so the page is throwing an error when it loads.

How do I avoid the error? It feels like I have a chicken and egg scenario.

Example:

```
$scope.Model.Charts.Electricity = {
  series: [
    name: "2014 Target",
    data: $scope.Model.Data.Json.Charts.Electricity.CurrentYearTarget
  ]
};
```

The `Electricity.CurrentYearTarget` property is the one that doesn't exist until the promise is completed:

```
promise.then(
  function(payload) {
    $scope.Model.Data.Json.Charts = payload.data;
});
```

The JSON is what then defines the objects that sit under `.Charts`. Example:

```
{"Electricity":
  {"CurrentYearTarget": 
     [10000.0,
      // snip
     10000.0]
  }
 }
```

OK, so what can I do to work with this? I suppose I could wrap all of my properties like `$scope.Model.Charts.Electricity` and so forth into a simple JavaScript `if` statement, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Initialize the variable at app startup or in your controller init code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you consider simplifying your approach somewhat, as `$scope.Model.Data.Json.Charts.Electricity.CurrentYearTarget` is somewhat verbose, and `Model`, `Data`, `Json` all mean the same thing really, you can probably cut some of these out.

However, this is beside the point, you can still acheive what you want to, just populate the data when the request *has* returned:

```
$scope.Model = { Data: { Json: { Charts: {} } } }

promise.then(
  function(payload) {

    $scope.Model.Data.Json.Charts = payload.data;
    $scope.Model.Charts.Electricity = {
      series: {
        name: "2014 Target",
        data: $scope.Model.Data.Json.Charts.Electricity.CurrentYearTarget
      }
    };
});
```